# Symfony denormalization: Recursive Denormalization not working

Tags: symfony, denormalization

I'am trying to desirialize the following Json structure into a `Profile` object

```
{
    "label": "lorem label",
    "info": {
        "name": "lorem name",
        "title": "lorem title"
    }
}
```

I have a class `Profile`

```
namespace App\Document;

class profile
{
   /**
    * @var string
    */
   protected $label;

   /**
    * @var Info
    */
   protected $info;

// getters and setters
}
```

and a class `Info`

```
namespace App\Document;

class Info
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected title;

    // getters & setters
}
```

my controller's code is the following

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Extractor\ReflectionExtractor;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Extractor\PhpDocExtractor;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use App\Document;

public function addProfile(Request $request, DocumentManager $dm, $profile_id)
{
    $phpDocNormalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new PhpDocExtractor());
    $reflectionNormalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor());
    $serializer = new Serializer([$phpDocNormalizer, $reflectionNormalizer], [new JsonEncoder()]);

    $profile = $serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), Profile::class, 'json');

    return new JsonResponse(Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

As the [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#recursive-denormalization-and-type-safety) says, i have the phpDocExtractor set and working, and the doc annotations are set too, the `PropertyInfo Component` is installed too. But i keep getting this `NotNormalizableValueException`:

`The type of the "info" attribute for class "App\Document\Profile" must be one of "App\Document\Info" ("array" given).`

I've been stuck with this one for a while now, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi ! I didn't work with Symfony for a while, but have you tried the denormalize function instead ? https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#recursive-denormalization-and-type-safety

Comment: Hello, yes i did, exactly like the docs says, and still i get the same exception saying that info is supposed to be an object but an array is given, logically this exception should be thrown on normalization, since denormalization expects an array as input, but i can't figure out what i'am missing.

Comment: do the setters have type hints as well (you omitted them, so I'm asking)

Comment: Yes, i made sure of that since i'am using ReflectionExtractor, setInfo has this signature `setInfo(Info $info)`, in addition i added the @var annotations.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function addProfile(Request $request, DocumentManager $dm, $profile_id)
{
    $extractors = new PropertyInfoExtractor([], [new PhpDocExtractor(), new ReflectionExtractor()]);
    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, $extractors);
    $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], [new JsonEncoder()]);
    $profile = $serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), Profile::class, 'json');

    return new JsonResponse(Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

You can find a more detailed example here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_info.html#usage